# How to create/update in DRF many-to-many fields?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

I have four models:

- `QuestStatus`
- `AdventureStatus`
- `QuestAdventureStatus` (consists of two
  things, foreign key fields to `QuestStatus` and `AdventureStatus`)
- `QuestAdventure` (has the M2M relationship to `QuestAdventureStatus`)

I have a serializer for `QuestAdventure` and `QuestAdventureStatus` exists as a field on my serializer:

```
quest_adventure_status = serializers.ListField(source='quest_adventure_status.all', required=False)
```

How do I properly create a new `QuestAdventure` and create `quest_adventure_status`(es) as well (updating too)? For creating, `quest_adventure_Status` is mandatory, but when I pass in my instance it's already serialized and not model objects?

Is there a proper way to deal with this in DRF?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you taking a look at drf-writable nested: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Comment: i rather not usee a third party library for this